# IPhone-Cocos2d: How to make a CCLayer that reflects another CCLayer

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cclayer

how can i create a new layer, that represents another layer i already have on the screen, just in a different position&scale?

Imagin it something like a minimap, that represents the current map the player is in, just that it is smaller, and appears on the edge of the screen and much smaller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone answered [my post on the cocos2d forums](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/9302).
it can be done using the CCRenderTexture class.